# BASH - Parsing values from a single line database file (

Tags: html, parsing, bash, curl

im trying to parse a database file retrieved from a website via curl, however I having trouble trying to figure out how to get the values.

This is an example of the file

```
{"Databasename":[{"Var1":"Var1Value","Var2":"Var2Value","Var3":"Var3Value"},{"Var1b":"Var1bValue","Var2b":"Var2bValue","Var3b":"Var3bValue"}],"foldername":{"dbTblcountvar":"dbTblcountvalue","filecountsize":"filecountsizvalue"}}
```

and with line break for better readability

```
{
 "Databasename":
 [
  {
   "Var1":"Var1aValue",
   "Var2":"Var2aValue",
   "Var3":"Var3aValue"
  },
  {
   "Var1":"Var1bValue",
   "Var2":"Var2bValue",
   "Var3":"Var3bValue"
  },
  {
   "Var1":"Var1cValue",
   "Var2":"Var2cValue",
   "Var3":"Var3cValue"
  }
 ],
"foldername":
  {
  "dbTblcountvar":"dbTblcountvalue",
  "filecountsize":"filecountsizvalue"
 }
}
```

asuming Var2 is always constant, how can i get its value? (Var2aValue,Var2bValue,Var2cValue,Var2dValue,.....)

In the example above the value im trying to get is an id for a file i need to send back to the server to download the file, and perform other operations on it.

Thanks

Comment: While you could parse something like this using tools like sed and awk in a bash shell, given that this looks like JSON, I would recommend using a higher level language to parse the document. Python has a built-in json module from Python 2.6+. Perl would be another option and has some json modules on CPAN.

Comment: Thanks Didnt know it was JSON, but after simply googling bash a json i found this cat fsfileman.txt | sed -e 's/[{}]/''/g' | awk -v k="text" '{n=split($0,a,","); for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print a[i]}' | grep '"Var2":' | sed 's/:/ /1' | awk -F" " '{ print $2 }'
   It gives me the needed values

Answer (score 2):

```
cat DownloadedFile.Ext | perl -pe 's/"Var2[abc]?":"(.+?)(?<![\\])"/\n\1\n/g' | grep -vPe '(?<!\\)"'
```

Those commands first put the Var2 (with optional a, b or c after) on a new line, then filter all lines that have a ".
I suppose that is a json file, so I avoid the matching of escaped " with this part of the regexp:

```
(?<!\\)
```